# Dispatch queue to animate SCNNode in ARKit

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, scenekit, arkit

I'm facing an issue when trying to periodically animate my nodes on an ARSession. I'm fetching data from Internet every 5 seconds and then with that data I update this nodes (shrink or enlarge).
My code looks something like this:

```swift
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { timer in
    fetchDataFromServer() {
        let fetchedData = $0
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            node1.update(fetchedData)
            node2.update(fetchedData)
            node3.update(fetchedData)
        }
        if stopCondition { timer.invalidate() }
    }
}
```

Problem is that when calling the updates I'm seeing a glitch in which the camera seems to freeze for a fraction of second and I see the following message in the console: `[Technique] World tracking performance is being affected by resource constraints [1]`
Update happens correctly, but the UX is really clumpsy if every 5 seconds I get these "short freezes"

I've tried creating a concurrent queue too:
`let animationQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "animationQueue", attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent)`
and call `animationQueue.async` instead of main queue but problem persists.
I'd appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT: Each of the subnodes on it's `update` method looks like this

```swift
private func growingGeometryAnimation(newHeight height: Float) -> CAAnimation{
    // Change height
    let grow = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "geometry.height")
    grow.toValue = height
    grow.fromValue = prevValue

    // .... and the position
    let move = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
    let newPosition = getNewPosition(height: height)
    move.toValue = newPosition.y + (yOffset ?? 0)

    let growGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    growGroup.animations = [grow, move]
    growGroup.duration = 0.5
    growGroup.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
    growGroup.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(
        name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    growGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    growGroup.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    growGroup.delegate = self

    return growGroup
}
self.addAnimation(growingGeometryAnimation(newHeight: self.value), forKey: "bar_grow_animation")
```

Answer (score 1):

To make any updates to the scene use `SCNTransaction`, it makes sure all of the changes are made on the appropriate thread.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { timer in
    fetchDataFromServer() {
        let fetchedData = $0

        SCNTransaction.begin()
        node1.update(fetchedData)
        node2.update(fetchedData)
        node3.update(fetchedData)
        SCNTransaction.commit()

        if stopCondition { timer.invalidate() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Lësha Turkowski. Thing is on the update methods of each node1, node2, node3 I'm using CAAnimation and adding it to the node. The SCNTransaction approach would work if I was just setting animatable properties of the node, if I understand correctly?

Comment: @leandrodemarco `SCNTransaction` is used to make changes to a scene atomically. It doesn't have to do anything with animatable properties (as far as I know), for example, Apple uses it to remove nodes from parents in their sample games. I haven't tried using it with `CAAnimation`s though, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.